# Google Drive API client secret

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I need your help, could any one explain me why **Google Drive API** uses ***client secret*** together with ***client id*** and what is the **role** that the ***client secret*** play in the authentication. process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it I as the login and password for your Application. Google identifies your application by the client id and its password client Secret.

When you create a application in Google Console a it assigned a client ID and a client secret (password) by the authorization server. The client ID and secret are unique to the client application on that authorization server.

When your client application requests access to a users data, the client application needs to authenticate itself by sending along the client ID and the client secret to the authorization server.